# Iron Pages selection by custom attribute

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have an `<iron-pages>` element with a few children, each of which is a `<section>` with some text content. By default, I can change the `selected` attribute of the `<iron-pages>` element, and the shown child `<section>` will change accordingly.

I want to use a custom attribute on the children to select them: `data-page`. I add the associated `attrForSelected="data-page"` attribute to the `<iron-pages>` and a `data-page` attribute to each child with a different string (such as `home`). With this system, however, the children are never displayed. Even a child with `data-page="home"` as an attribute will not show when the `<iron-pages>` `selected` attribute is set to `home`.

What am I doing wrong with custom attributes for selection?

Comment: Have you tried to bind to `data-page$="{{page}}"`?

Comment: While not actually the solution to the main problem, this was needed too, thanks! I keep forgetting about the new binding format (especially when working from ol Polymer 0.5 docs), and without this the page data doesn't update correctly after loading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`attrForSelected="data-page"` should be `attr-for-selected="data-page"`
CamelCase properties are translated to dashed attributes ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping)).

Comment: That was it, thanks! Not sure why I didn't catch a camel case HTML attribute…